# Observe_field in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to accomplish an observe_field in rails 3.

In rails 2.3.5 I have :-

```
 <%= observe_field 'query',  :frequency => 2,
                            :update => "search_results",                                
                            :url => {:controller => params[:area], :action => "search",:area =>  params[:area]},
                            :method=>:get,
                            :with => "query" %>
```

Which works fine, checking my text_field_tag "query" and  updating my "search_results" every two seconds. This is what I am trying to simulate using prototype.

At the moment I have in a basic application in Rails 3:-

```
<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() { 
$('search').observe('change', 
respondToChange());
});
</script>
```

or

```
<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {
new Form.Element.Observer(
'search',
1, 
respondToChange()
) });
</script>
```

Both of which triggers the respondToChange function when the page loads, despite the "dom:loaded", and then does not observes anymore.

Does anyone have any idea of how I might obtain the repeated observer checks on my "search" text_field_tag.

Comment: Man, I suggest you work a little bit more on the question formatting, it's kinda messy.

Comment: Thanks I just learn't how to and I hope I have edited it correctly

Answer (score 0):

With thanks to "themiddleman" and "agnaki" somewhere out there in the ether, I have solved the problem:

Use `respondToChange`, not `respondToChange()`

As the parentheses () execute the function, whereas without () it references it.

```
$('search').observe('change', respondToChange);
 // only triggers when the focus is moved away from the text_field.

new Form.Element.Observer(
  'search',
  1,
respondToChange
) }); 

//................................repeatedly checks the text_field,every 1 second, and call the function if there is a any change.
```

Comment: I have cracked it.   $('search').up('form').submit()

Answer (score 0):

Here is my full code if anyone is interested. This code observes the text_field_tag "search" every 2 seconds, and if there is a change in the value, it triggers a search automatically. The submit button can now be done away with, I think. I might add `:autocomplete => "off", :onKeyPress=>"return disableEnterKey(event)") %>` to the text_field_tag to disable the return key, not sure.

In my index.html.erb I have:

```
<h1>Listing homepages</h1>
<div id = "testsearch">
   <%=render :partial => 'homepage'%>     
</div>
<%= form_tag homepages_path, :method => 'get', :remote => true do %>
<%= label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %> 
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
<%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
<%end%>

<%= set_focus_to_id 'search' %>               // I have a helper "set_focus_to_id"

<script>
document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {   // ensures the page is loaded first
new Form.Element.Observer(                    // Observes the text_field_tag every 2 seconds
  'search',
  2, 
  respondToChange                         //refrences the function in the Layout <head> 
)                                         // on a change in search calls respondToChange
});
</script>
<br />
<%= link_to 'New Homepage', new_homepage_path %>
```

In my application Layout head I have:

```
<script>
function respondToChange() {
$('search').up('form').submit()            // The ".up finds the form in the DOM"
};
</script
```

In my controller#index I have:

```
 def index
  @homepages = Homepage.search(params[:search]) //".search method is in the Model"
  respond_to do |format|
   format.html # index.html.erb
   format.xml  { render :xml => @homepages }
   format.js
 end
end
```

In my Model I have:

```
def self.search(search_item)
   if search_item
    self.where('section LIKE ?', "%#{search_item}%")    //Handles the ajax call.
   else
    self.all                                            //Handles the html call on startup.
   end
end
```

In the helper I have:

```
def set_focus_to_id(id)
  javascript_tag("$('#{id}').focus()");
end
```

In the "_homepage" partial I have:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Section</th>
    <th>Link</th>
    <th>Description</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
 </tr>

<% for homepage in @homepages %>

  <tr>
    <td><%= homepage.id %></td>
    <td><%= homepage.section %></td>
    <td><%= homepage.link %></td>
    <td><%= homepage.description %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', homepage %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_homepage_path(homepage) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', homepage, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
  </tr>
<%end%>

</table>
```

And in the index.js.erb I have:

```
$('testsearch').update("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'homepage') %>");
```

If anyone has any comments on how I could improve this, please contact me or say so.

Answer (score 0):

I think I have now solved the problem of doing an ajax call via programming. I will have to check it out in all types of browsers, but at the moment it is working in Firefox and Safari. I have now also moved both javascript "document.observe("dom:loaded" and the function it calls "respondToChange()" to the application head with content_for. All other files remain the same.

In my index.html.erb I now have:-

```
<h1>Listing homepages</h1>
<div id = "testsearch">
     <%=render :partial => 'homepage'%>     
</div>
<%= form_tag homepages_path, :method => 'get', :remote => true do %>
    <%= label_tag(:search, "Search for:") %> 
<%= text_field_tag :search, params[:search]%>
 <%= submit_tag "search", :name => nil %>
<%end%>

<%= set_focus_to_id 'search' %>               

<% content_for :search_javascript do %>

function respondToChange() {

    var pars = 'search=' + $('search').getValue()

        new Ajax.Request("<%= homepages_path %>" ,{
        method: 'get',
        parameters: pars
    }); 
};

document.observe("dom:loaded", function() {   
    new Form.Element.Observer(                
      'search',
      2, 
      respondToChange

    )                                         
});

<% end %>

<br />
<%= link_to 'New Homepage', new_homepage_path %>
```

In my application layout file I now have:-
    
    
    
      
      GardenR3
      <%= stylesheet_link_tag :all %>
      <%= javascript_include_tag :defaults %>
      <%= csrf_meta_tag %>

```
<script>
 <%= yield :search_javascript %>
</script>

</head>
<body>

<%= yield %>

</body>
</html>
```